# Prevent click+drag selections in multiple select lists

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiple select list and I want to disable the ability to make selections by using click+drag within it, so that only one new value can be selected per click – but at the same time I want to continue to operate the list as a ‘multiple’ select so that I can still select multiple values using control+click.

I’ve tried fiddling around with onselectstart and ondragstart in the tags, but they do not seem to do anything within a multiple select list. Example:

```
<Select id="foo" name="foo[]" multiple="yes" onselectstart="return false" onchange="ajaxFunction()" Size="5">  
    <option value="" selected>Any</option>  
    <option value="bar"  ondragstart=" return false;">foo</option>  
    <option value="foobar">bar</option> 
    <option value="barfoo">foobar</option>
</Select>
```

I suspect I may need to use javascript rather than pure html. Notably the select list triggers an onchange event, which may be a key to this - one idea that springs to mind is to somehow count the number of selections triggering each onchange event and if more than one then those values are not processed in the onchange event or the event is cancelled entirely. Hopefully however there's a simpler solution.

Comment: Please post some code and maybe a screenshot to clarify the specific situation. JSFiddle is a good tool to troubleshoot HTML+CSS+JS issues.

Comment: OK edited - I've taken the superfluous info out and added some sample code. Thanks for the JSFiddle suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I couldn’t find a way of disabling drag in html but I did manage to come up with a function that neutralizes multiple new selections by refreshing the page. Seems like a lot of fancy footwork for not much effect but anyway it works for my purposes. I’ll leave this question open for a day or two before marking this as the best answer just incase anyone comes up with a better solution.

```
function ajaxfunction(sel)
    {
        var total_selections_counter = 0;
            //i.e. total selections passed to the onchange event, whether selected previously or not
        var overlapping_selections_counter = 0;
            //i.e. selections which were already selected and are also re-selected and passed to the onchange event
        for (var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i++)
            {
                if(sel.options[i].selected)
                    {
                        total_selections_counter++;
                    }
                if(sel.options[i].selected && sel.options[i].defaultSelected)
                    {
                        overlapping_selections_counter++;
                    }
            }
        var new_selections_counter = total_selections_counter - overlapping_selections_counter;
        if(new_selections_counter > 1)
            {
                location.reload(true);
            }
        else
            {
               alert("continue processing");
            }
    }
```